# iOS tool to measure battery drain

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, battery

Is there a way of measuring battery drain of an iOS application?

I was looking for such things but I didn't find any satisfying results. Maybe more like http://mobileenerlytics.com but it's not something that we can run with iOS I guess.

What I want to achieve:

1. I want to somehow measure our current state of battery draining.
2. Profile / find some issues connected to battery draining.
3. Measure new state of battery draining and compare to the origin state.

That would be perfect to have a clear information, that could be also applied into CI .
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't mentioned trying the in-built battery diagnostic tools in xcode. Does this not suit your needs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithInstruments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [MetricKit](https://nshipster.com/metrickit/), it only works for iOS 13, but I think it's enough for measuring.